# Update single-row table in pl/pgsql-while loop

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

```sql
create table data(a1 float, a2 float);
insert into data values(1::float, 1::float);

do $$
declare 
   counter integer := 0;
begin
   while counter < 50 loop
      --SAVE THIS INTO DATA      
      SELECT a1-0.1*random(),
              a2-0.1*random()
      from data group by a1, a;
      --SAVE THIS INTO DATA (END)
      counter := counter + 1;
   end loop;
end$$;
```

I would like to save the values of `a1` and `a2` into the first tuple of data. (Basically a running tally)

**How can I save the result of a `SELECT` into a existing table?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be easier with a `PRIMARY KEY` on the table:

```
create table data(id int primary key, a1 float, a2 float);
insert into data values(1, 1, 1);
select * from data;
 id | a1 | a2 
----+----+----
  1 |  1 |  1

update data set a1 = a1 - 0.1*random(), a2 = a2 - 0.1*random() where id =1;
select * from data;
 id |         a1         |        a2        
----+--------------------+------------------
  1 | 0.9039355377682678 | 0.98859843416964
```

Then incorporate the `UPDATE` into the counter loop:

```
do $$              
declare 
   counter integer := 0;
begin
   while counter < 50 loop
      --SAVE THIS INTO DATA      
     update data set a1 = a1 - 0.1*random(), a2 = a2 - 0.1*random() where id =1;  
    --SAVE THIS INTO DATA (END)
      counter := counter + 1;
   end loop;
end$$;

select * from data;
 id |         a1          |         a2         
----+---------------------+--------------------
  1 | -1.3146675853588001 | -1.216530003992667
```

Comment: Thnak you, i am still a bit new to SQL, so this is the perfect solution. Thank you for your quick answer.